# Text interspersed with images using Bulma

Tags: html, css, nuxt.js, bulma

I've been thinking about how to this for a few days now, and I almost found a way to do it, but it's very very messy. I'm trying to intersperse images with text in my Nuxt app. I'm using Bulma as a CSS framework. The structure I want this specific page to have is the following:

[image: Wireframe of the specific page]

I managed to make something like that with a v-for and some v-ifs:

```html
<div class="body tile is-parent">
      <div class="tile is-ancestor is-flex-wrap-wrap">
        <template v-for="(item, index) in body">
          <div class="tile is-parent is-12" style="margin-left: 4%">
            <h1 v-if="item.title" class="title bodyContent mt-5 tile is-child" style="font-size: 25px;"> {{ item.txt }}
            </h1>
          </div>

          <template v-if="!item.title && post.attributes.media.data !== null && index > 1 && (index % 2) != 0">
            <div class="tile is-parent is-6" style="margin-left: 4%">
              <div :ref="'paragraphImg' + index" class="tile is-child" v-html="$md.render(item.txt)"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="tile is-parent is-4 imgContainer" style="margin-left: 4%; margin-right: 4%">
              <img class="tile is-child" :src="imgSource">
            </div>
          </template>

          <template v-if="!item.title && (index % 2) == 0" lang="md">
            <div v-html="$md.render(item.txt)" class="bodyContent"></div>
            <br v-if="index < body.length - 1">
          </template>
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And some styles:

```css
.body {
  background-color: #bdd0db;
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

.bodyContent {
  margin-left: 5%;
}

.imgContainer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This only displays paragraphs next to images, but it doesn't manages the image's size, that's most of the time bigger than the paragraph's height. And it makes the paragraph isolated from the rest.

I'm trying to fix this by getting the paragraph's height and changing the picture's based on it. But I'm wondering if there's an easier way to do this, as it's a fairly common distribution on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

So, turns out I just had to nest some tiles to no to worry about the image's size. By using the Bulma's vertical tile for the text, and having a few paragraphs together, the image's height is forced to be the same as the paragraphs'.

```html
<div class="body tile is-parent">
      <div class="tile is-ancestor is-flex-wrap-wrap">
        <template v-for="(item, index) in body">
          <div v-if="item.title" class="tile is-parent is-12" style="margin-left: 4%">
            <h1 class="title bodyContent mt-5 tile is-child" style="font-size: 25px;"> {{ item.txt }}
            </h1>
          </div>

          <template v-else-if="post.attributes.media.data !== null && index > 1 && (index % 2) != 0">
            <div class="tile is-vertical is-6" style="margin-left: 4%">
              <div class="tile is-parent">
                <div :ref="'paragraphImg' + index" class="tile is-child" v-html="$md.render(item.txt)"></div>
              </div>

              <div class="tile is-parent">
                <div :ref="'paragraphImg' + index" class="tile is-child" v-html="$md.render(item.txt)"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            

            <div class="tile is-parent is-4 imgContainer" style="margin-left: 4%; margin-right: 4%">
              <img class="tile is-child" :src="'http://localhost:1337' + post.attributes.media.data[0].attributes.formats.small.url">
            </div>
          </template>

          <template v-if="!item.title && (index % 2) == 0" lang="md">
            <div v-html="$md.render(item.txt)" class="bodyContent"></div>
            <br v-if="index < body.length - 1">
          </template>
        </template>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here I'm using the same text for both pargraphs, but you get the idea.